# How to save an untouched new record

Tags: ms-access-2010, record, autosave, subform

after reading a lot in this forum (and also in others), I still haven't found a solution for my problem. It's a classical scenario : a **Customer** creates an **Order**, which in turn has **OrderItems**.
So my tables are as follow :

**tbl_Customer**
**cust_Id** as Long (primary key, autoincrement)
**cust_Name** as String
**cust_Adress** as String
**cust_Phone** as String
etc

**tbl_Order**
**ord_Id** as Long (primary key, autoincrement)
**ord_CustId** as Long (references as foreign key field **cust_Id** in table **tbl_Customer**)
**ord_Date** as Date

**tbl_OrderItem**
**oi_OrdId** as Long (references as foreign key field **ord_Id** in table **tbl_Order**)
**oi_ArtId** as Long (references as foreign key field art_Id in table tbl_Article which is not relevant   in this scenario)
**oi_Count** as Integer (quantity of article(s))
**oi_Price** as Double (price of article)

As you can see it is a not so complicated m:n relationship between customers and articles which are ordered.

Beside these tables I created in Access a form **frmCustomer** (based on tbl_Customer) which owns a subform **frmOrder** (based on tbl_Order). These two forms are connected by fields **cust_Id** and **ord_CustId**.
SubForm **frmOrder** in turn has a subForm **frmOrderItem** (based on table tbl_OrderItem). They are connected by fields **ord_Id** and **oi_OrdId**.

Some example data inserted in these tables are shown correct. Switching customers results in showing its orrders and orderitems. So far so good.

Now I want to insert a new order, and adding some orderitems to it.
If I click on button "New empty record" (record-navigation pane) of subForm frmOrder, a new empty order-record is created with empty fields and empty subform orderitem.
When I now insert a new orderitem and try to store it, an error message appears, saying the record cannot be stored because field **oi_OrdId** cannot be null.
That's true, because the order-record is not yet stored, and hence autoincremented field **ord_Id** is not yet filled. Only if I edit a field in the until now untouched order-record (for example orderdate) and leave that field, the record is stored, and the field **ord_Id** is filled, and also field **oi_OrdId** in form **frmOrderItem**.
But, because the fields **ord_CustId** (=[Forms]![frmCustomer]![cust_Id], value copied from parent form **frmCustomer**) and **ord_Date** ( =Date() ) have default-values, I don't want to edit a field first.
I would like to enter immediatly orderitems.

Is there an event (-procedure) I can use to save the untouched order-record (how ?) automatically, when I enter a field of subform **frmOrderItem** ?
Or has somebody of the community a helpful solution ?
And by the way, is there a way to access a new, not yet saved record ?

Thank you very much in advance for your help

ulofb

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to insert a new order, and adding some orderitems to it. If
> I click on button "New empty record" (record-navigation pane) of
> subForm frmOrder

Don't. Do it the other way round. Block record inserts in the subform for a new order record. After insert/save of the order form, enable record inserts in the subform.

Comment: Hi Gustav, thanks a lot for your answer.
My problem was to save the order-record, to have a new order number to be used in the order-item(s).
But the DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord function didn't work. First the record's attribute dirty has to be set to true. 
This requires, that an bound, updatable field of the form has the focus. So I wrote a little procedure that does exactly this.
For now, this procedure is called when I click a (test-)cmdbutton. So now I have to find a good place (event) to put this procedure.  

So thank you very much again for your tip  

ulofb